# Unity Editor: long Application.WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete "Self ms" time after SceneManager.LoadScene

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

I am loading my game scene by calling [`SceneManager.LoadScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html). However, I am occasionally getting long load times when loading a game scene in my builds. I have not been able to reproduce this consistently, but while debugging this issue, I noticed that I can reproduce this problem every time in the Unity Editor (2017.3) on the first play.

If I enter play mode for the first time after the Unity Editor is launched and then click an in-game button to load my game scene, **the profiler shows that `Application.WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete` is taking ~9000 ms. I am having trouble debugging it because the time is spent in "Self ms".**

If I re-enter play mode and repeat the same steps, subsequent runs show that `WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete` only takes ~200 ms. The time jumps back up to 9000 ms if I re-open the Unity Editor and repeat the same steps.

How can I debug and fix this long "Self ms" time in `WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete`? I am also wondering what could be causing this long delay only on the first play after opening the Unity Editor (and what persists in the Unity editor between play mode runs).

---

My profiler hierarchy looks like this:

```
EarlyUpdate.UpdatePreloading
- Loading.UpdatePreloading
-- UpdatePreloading
--- Application.WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete [*takes about 9000 ms, 8500 self ms*]
---- PreloadSingleStep [*takes about 500 ms*]
----- Application.LoadLevelAsync Integrate
----- Loading.AwakeFromLoad
----- (...)
```

See below for a screenshot of the profiler on the first play after Unity Editor is launched (note that Deep Profile is off, but the result is similar with Deep Profile on):

[image: record-slow-issue.PNG]

See below for a screenshot of profiler on subsequent playthroughs (and note that "Self ms" is down to a more reasonable ~200 ms rather than ~9000 ms):

[image: record-no-longer-slow-after-first-editor-play]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Debugging approach**

As a first step, I debugged the problem by systematically deleting GameObjects in the scene that was being loaded to identify which GameObject was causing the issue.

Doing this, I found that the long loading times disappeared when I deleted a particular GameObject from the scene.

(I did not investigate how to debug a long `Application.WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete` "Self ms" time directly given that I was able to solve my issue with my previous approach.)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this error before on an older version of Unity (2017). I have not seen it since I upgraded